# shadow volume - non-manifold objects

Tags: c++, opengl, shadow, stencil-buffer

I have doubts regarding the creation of shadow volumes
for non-manifold objects, specially when the objects
have dangling faces.

For instance:

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [ricfow at www.dt.fee.unicamp.br](http://www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/%7Ericfow/twoDanglingFaces.jpg))</sub>

where we have a box (brown) and two connected faces (white) on the top.
The standard z-pass and z-fail algorithms fail to produce
correct shadows. Where can I find theoretical material
to improve the standard algorithms to cope with
more complex cases (as the one above)?

Comment: Afaik shadow volumes only work with closed volumes. You may want to try shadow mapping instead.

Answer (score 0):

The paper: 
A Shadow Volume Algorithm for Opaque and Transparent Non-Manifold Casters, B. Kim, K. Kim and G. Turk, Journal of Graphics Tools, 13(3):1-14, 2008

presents interesting improvements to cope with non-manifold geometry. The geometry presented in the above picture can be handled by the proposed approach.

Best regards,
ricfow